# How can I tell cppcheck to ignore certain errors?

Tags: cppcheck

i want to be able to write 2 sets of rules:

1. Ruleset which ignores errors like

   - Uninitialized variable
   - variableScope
2. Ruleset which includes ALL , but i can manually ignore one or more rule sets

Keeping in view that :

cppcheck will check for memory leaks.
For classes the checking is only made if "--all" is given. The reason is that there will be false positives if an instance is deallocated automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Cppcheck terminology.. a rule is a user-defined pattern that Cppcheck should look out for in the code and report about.

> 1.Ruleset which ignores errors like

Use suppressions. See --suppression-list and --suppress. You can use -i to skip entire files.

> 2.Ruleset which includes ALL , but i can manually ignore one or more rule sets

Use --enable.